# Filter based on another table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am building a tinder-like rating system for images.

I need to find an image that has the nearest rating to the provided image.
And the pair of those images are not present in the comparasion table.

The first part is straightforward and looks like this

```sql
SELECT images.file_path, images.id
FROM images JOIN ratings ON images.id = ratings.image 
WHERE images.id != ? AND ratings.label = ? 
ORDER BY abs(? - ratings.mu) ASC
```

And then I have a table containing the following information and I need assure that result of the first query don't produce the pair that is contained in that table

```
img1: Integer - Image id
img2: Integer - Image id
outcome: Integer - Not relevant to question
```

Right now I am using SQLite for testing but solution that works on multiples DB's would be great for further development

**Example**
Image table (file_path omitted)

```
id, label, mu
1, 1, 1.5
2, 1, 2.0
3, 1, 2.5
4, 1, 3.5
```

Comparison table (outcome ommited)

```
img1, img2
1, 2
2, 3
3, 4
```

Example outcome for image with id 1 = img with id 3. Because its rating is closest to 1.5 and can't be image 2 because this pair is inside the comparison table

Comment: Your 1st query does not return a pair of image ids. Also, why NULLS FIRST? Post sample data and expected results to clarify what you want.

Comment: There is very little information on what the structure of the second table is but assuming that it has the pair of images, try to perform a left join with the second table based on the image pair and check where the image id column from the second table is null. This would filter out the records which is already present in the second table.

Comment: @forpas null firsts can be omitted forgot to remove that it was there to prefer unranked images. I added example data and example output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `NOT EXISTS` to filter out what shouldn't be there.

> ```
> WITH img AS (
>   SELECT id as image_id, label, mu
>   FROM images
>   WHERE id = 1
> )
> SELECT 
>   images.file_path
> , images.id as image_id
> , ratings.mu as rating_mu
> , ratings.label as rating_label
> FROM images 
> CROSS JOIN img
> INNER JOIN ratings
>   ON images.id = ratings.image 
>  AND ratings.label = img.label 
> WHERE NOT EXISTS (
>   SELECT 1
>   FROM comparison c
>   WHERE images.id in (c.img1, c. img2) 
>     AND img.image_id in (c.img1, c. img2)
> )
> ORDER BY abs(img.mu - ratings.mu) ASC
> LIMIT 1;
> ```
>
> ```
> file_path    | image_id | rating_mu | rating_label
> :----------- | -------: | --------: | -----------:
> /img/foo.png |        3 |       2.5 |            1
> ```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8dbdb11c6c8bb1a4cec5c2bc98c11ac5)*